# Does A woman has a right on her husband for providing a separate house?

Tags: fiqh, practical-islam, husband-wife, parents

As from many Hadith and sunnah  it is prove that man should provide a separate room to his wife.Can a woman has right on her husband that he provide him a separate house  on her demand ,if  he is living with is parent  and they can live together without any issue? If yes than Is it okay for a man to leave his parents for her wife?

Comment: The wife has the right to be provided accommodation, she does not have the right to force the husband to live with her in that accommodation, other than spending the night.

Comment: I believe UmH is correct. FWIW Islam is not just all about laws. Love and companionship are highly instructed in Islam. The prophet said the best of you in faith is one who is the best to his wife. If a husband can provide her wife with a separate house where she feels loved, comfortable and as a result would be closer to her husband then its likely that she will spend more time making the house a warm, loving place where she and her husband and children will feel comfortable. A husband who just sticks to the rules and doesn't take measures to please his wife is not the kind our prophet likes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course its duty of man to give separate shelter to woman , from many Hadits it is clear and understood ,but stop a moment just realize *and also concern with scholars .........*

Because this is depending on scenario and situation of man. Can man afford it easily and its income is enough to  endurance the expenditures easily or not . 
can man give proper time,importance and service(denoting religious devotion/loyalty)
to his parents ,
so sometime its difficult but

**its women right for demanding separate house.**

man have to manage it(that can influence by woman pressurizing )

Comment: Evidences supporting your claims would make this answer more profitable (see [answer]).

Answer (score 0):

yes according to Islam its is woman right to have seprate home because the main duty of woman is that to take care of their childern and home not to takecare of their father bin law and mother in law so if the woman asked to have seprate home husband should provide him a home.

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and our model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help]. Your post would profit from evidences supporting your claims. See [answer].

Answer (score 0):

As per teachings of Islam it is  clearly mentioned for parents  that whenever  their children grew elder they should make a separate home for them and marry them. In the same context if a wife claim her husband for separate house, husband is bound to provide separate home for her wife. If  wife does not want to  live with the parents of husband Islam allows her to do so.In this case husband himself is bound to take care his parents and provide a separate home as per wishes of his wife

Answer (score -1):

A wife has only a right to be provided by separate room not a whole house

Comment: This answer would benefit from evidences supporting your claims. All the wives of the prophet had different "houses" with different entries.